# Tag Synonymns to merge

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Please post in this question all tag synonyms which you think should be combined. Having too many ways to refer to a given topic is just confusing, and it fragments things.

Answer (score 9):

[political-party](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-party)→ [parties](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parties)

"Political" seems redundant, given where we are.

Answer (score 7):

Also [us](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us) -> [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)

Maybe [parliament](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parliament) <-> [parliamentary](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parliamentary) (not sure which way to go)

Comment: Personally, I prefer [tag:parliament]

Comment: There are parliamentary processes and then there is a parliament.

Comment: There is also a [misspelled tag](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parlamentary) that should probably be removed.

Answer (score 7):

[united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) → [usa](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa)

[health-insurance-exhange](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-insurance-exhange) → [healthcare](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/healthcare)

[voting-systems](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting-systems) → [voting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting)

Comment: See http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/q/35/78 for the question of USA. Otherwise, vote for the other two.

Answer (score 5):

[taxes](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxes) ↔ [taxation](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taxation)

No idea which way, though - perhaps synonymize both to [tax](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tax)?

Answer (score 4):

[temporal-vacancy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temporal-vacancy) to [temporary-vacancy](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temporary-vacancy)

...which is what I assume the author meant -- although I'm not sure that this deserves a tag at all.

Comment: It doesn't deserve a tag.

Answer (score 3):

[uk](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk) → [united-kingdom](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-kingdom)

Answer (score 2):

[usa](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa)->[united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)

Comment: I'd say the other way around as united states is still an abbreviation but USA is more specific and is a full abbreviation.

Comment: See http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/q/35/78 for this specific question.

Answer (score 2):

[british-politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/british-politics)→ [uk](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk)

I know that Great Britain and the United Kingdom are technically not the same thing, but they're used interchangeably in practice.

Comment: I though GB and the UK were the same but England != gb or UK

Comment: @Chad: See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminology_of_the_British_Isles).

Answer (score 2):

[britain](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/britain) -> [uk](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk)

"Britain" (but **not** "Great Britain") is very commonly used as a synonym for "UK".

Comment: They're technically different, but [uk] is probably the better tag in practice. Looking through the questions currently tagged [britain], most of them seem to be about the UK as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

Merge economy, economics, and economic policy into economics.

Answer (score 0):

commonwealth -> commonwealth-of-nations

british-commonwealth -> commonwealth-of-nations

Comment: commonwealth can easily be a tag on its own. There are many of them out there, even in the US. It is a style of community and governance.

Comment: "commonwealth" and "british-commonwealth" are distinct, as @KevinPeno says - and "british-commonwealth" is the more common name for that institution.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_of_Nations - 'The Commonwealth of Nations, normally referred to as the Commonwealth and formerly known as the British Commonwealth, is an intergovernmental organisation of 54 independent member states.' It is bigger than the EU, it is just like saying US is interchangeable. United States could refer to some nations who decided to work together (They are then united states) or the united Mexican states.

Comment: *the Commonwealth* is still different than the concept of a commonwealth nation. I agree with your other merge though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested [election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election) <- [electoral](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electoral) and [polling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polling) <- [opinion-polling](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opinion-polling).  Feel free to vote them up to approval.

Answer (score 0):

To my feeling the tag [election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election) is misnamed. I would prefer it to be called [elections](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elections). Common usage is *Today, parliamentary elections are being held in X*, not *a parliamentary election is being held in X*.

Answer (score 0):

[president](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president) -> [head-of-state](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/head-of-state)