# United States tag synonym with USA?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [Tag Synonyms to merge](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/tag-synonymns-to-merge) question currently contains only the suggestion to merge [us](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us) and [usa](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) into [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states). While this is probably appropriate for the vast majority of questions asked with either tag, it is not technically correct, although no question so far deals with the country officially called the "United Mexican States".

How should this, and in general ambiguities with one, erm, dominant resolution, be handled? (wikipedia, for one, redirects United States to United States of America with a note and link to a [disambiguation page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_%28disambiguation%29) on top.

Comment: Does anyone attempt to tag the "United Mexican States" as the us on the Internet? I'm pretty sure the answer is no

Answer (score 7):

A quick survey of other sites.

- Money uses United-States
- Skeptics uses United-States
- The Workplace uses united-states

I can't find the tag anywhere else. So, I'm going to say be consistent, use [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states).

Comment: Going by that, we also need to change [tag:uk] to [tag:united-kingdom] and [tag:eu] to [tag:european-union]. To follow the pattern, we may end up with [tag:north-atlantic-treaty-organization] and even [tag:south-asian-association-for-regional-cooperation] :P Politics is a world of acronyms, and I don't see the problem with keeping them here. Tag wikis will clear up what we mean

Comment: Some acronyms might be fine, but I think countries should be spelled out. NATO would be fine.

Comment: In which case, maybe we should target the "proper" political name of the countries especially as that at present political history is on-topic here, and historically speaking, "United States" does not purely represent the ones in America - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_(disambiguation)

Comment: Wikipedia also uses United States.

Answer (score 3):

`united-states` (or `us`) is just [too generic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_%28disambiguation%29), `usa` seems to be the best match. That’s how it is called usually in contexts outside of this country.

Comment: I'd much prefer `USA` - it's immediately obvious and short, and probably faster to auto complete (I would imagine people start typing U, then S when looking for a tag about the US).

Comment: United stats should be synonymized into USA too though, so you can type "united" and get USA as a suggestion

Comment: Completely agree with [tag:usa], having both [tag:us] and [tag:united-states] as synonyms

Answer (score 3):

I've merged and synonymized these all with [united-states](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) for now. Easy enough to change in the future if a different scheme appears to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer USA.

First, this is the abbreviation of the full name of that country.

Second, the abbreviation USA is used in many other languages, f.e. in Polish. US is not so widely known there.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst USA is less ambiguous some people will still use US and United States. I very much doubt that United States is used to refer to the UMS as the USA is more widely referred to/well known.

I'd say that USA is preferable but united-states and US should be tag synonyms.

Perhaps have all merge into united-states-of-america which is in no way an abbreviation nor is it ambiguous.