# Merge [tag:britain] and [tag:uk]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[britain](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/britain) is not *quite* the same as the [uk](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk).  For example, on Wikipedia, see [Terminology of the British Isles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminology_of_the_British_Isles), [Glossary of names for the British](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_names_for_the_British), and [British Isles naming dispute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Isles_naming_dispute).

Although some legislation *does* exclusively apply to Great Britain (UK but without Northern Ireland), that is not true for any question currently tagged [britain](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/britain).

Therefore, I propose that [britain](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/britain) should be merged into [uk](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uk).

(This was proposed [years ago](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/60/130), but never happened — probably because it's not 100% correct?)

Obligatory CGP Grey video explaining the different terms:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rNu8XDBSn10

Comment: -1 for not linking to CGP Grey video explaining the difference

Comment: @user4012 Huh·?

Comment: see my edit. The notional downvote was notional :)

Comment: @user4012. The CGP Grey video has a couple of inaccuracies.